# MASM, address 9ffffh

Tags: debugging, assembly, masm

i have some strange things.
Here is example of code.

```
CODESEGMENT segment
    assume CS: CODESEGMENT, DS: CODESEGMENT, SS: NOTHING, ES:NOTHING
    org 100h
    BEGIN:      mov AX, 9fffh
                mov DS, AX
                mov CX, DS:000FH
                ;-----------------------------------------------------
                ;End of program, exit to DOS
                ;-----------------------------------------------------
                mov AX, 4c00h
                int 21h
CODESEGMENT ends
end BEGIN
```

and this code

```
CODESEGMENT segment
    assume CS: CODESEGMENT, DS: CODESEGMENT, SS: NOTHING, ES:NOTHING
    org 100h
    BEGIN:      mov AX, 9000h
                mov DS, AX
                mov BX, [0FFFFH]
                ;-----------------------------------------------------
                ;End of program, exit to DOS
                ;-----------------------------------------------------
                mov AX, 4c00h
                int 21h
CODESEGMENT ends
end BEGIN
```

I think that when i get offset from DS i have, for example this,

```
DS = 9000h
offset = FFFFh

DS = 9000h * 10h = 90000h
                   +
                   0FFFFh
                   =
                   9FFFFh
```

Thinking this way i wrote this two codes.
And i thought this codes did the same thing - reading to CX two bytes from address 9FFFFh, but i looked in masm debugger (afd) and understood that i was wrong.

First code:[image: DS = 9fffh, offset = 000fh]

Second code[image: DS = 9000h, offset = ffffh]

I use masm because i'm student, and i get used to it. 
Please can some tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: The two bytes at offset 0xFFFF in a 64-bit segment are the byte at 0xFFFF and the byte at 0x0000, which is the first byte of the segment. A segment can only address 64k, and you're fetching the 64k+1-th byte, which wraps around to the beginning. The first piece of code doesn't have that problem.

Comment: But still, why are content i have in debugger differ from each other? I think i didn underastand you, i mean when i have ds = 9000h and then then i have offset ffffh, i don't get an real adress like 9ffffh ?

Comment: I don't see where you're looking.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad english. I understood about two bytes. Am i right that when i add offset to segment registr then i get 20-bit real address to memory cell?

Comment: Well, yes, but if the second or later bytes of the operand cause the address to overflow 16 bits, the seventeenth bit is NOT carried into the DS...it is just dropped. So if DS is 0x9000, and BX is 0xFFFF, then a 16-bit read will fetch the bytes at 0x9FFFF and 0x90000, NOT 0xA0000.